# Successively loading data into buffer

Tags: c#, mysql

I have data which takes a lot of time to load from database so what i do is load it into local memory and use it from there. From time to time i need to refresh it.

```
List<DataInMyMemory> data;
===============
data.add(LoadData(1)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(2)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(3)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(4)) // 4 sec
```

Up is already loaded data with 4 items in list ( i have 200+ items and will have a lot more). When i reload i do it two ways:

```
data = new List<DataInMyMemory>();
===============
data.add(LoadData(1)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(2)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(3)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(4)) // 4 sec
```

With this first way, i need to empty current data and load new one. Since new one need about 20 min to load, if anyone try to access it they will get null as data is still not loaded.

Then i came up with another solution which is

```
List<DataInMyMemory> tempData = new List<DataInMemory>();
data.add(LoadData(1)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(2)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(3)) // 4 sec
data.add(LoadData(4)) // 4 sec
data = tempData;
```

this way data will be available but if someone try getting data from first user (which is already loaded but in temp list) he will get old data and i want it to be as relative as possible.

So is there a way to achieve successively reloading items in list.

Down is full code how i am doing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TDShop.User.GetMaxID(); i++)
{
    //VPCene is data list of type List<Tuple<int, List<WebShop.Cena>>>
    VPCene.Add(new Tuple<int, List<WebShop.Cena>>(i + 1, TDShop.User.GetVPCene(i + 1)));
}
```

and here is function `TDShop.User.GetVPCene()` which takes 4 seconds to finish (Since i load id 200+ times it is a lot of time)

```
public static List<WebShop.Cena> GetVPCene(int UserID)
{
    if (!AR.Initialized)
        throw new Exception(AR.NotInitializedMessage);

    try
    {
        List<WebShop.Cena> MaxCene = new List<WebShop.Cena>();
        List<WebShop.Cena> MinCene = new List<WebShop.Cena>();
        List<WebShop.Cena> CeneZaKorisnika = new List<WebShop.Cena>();

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(AR.ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            List<Tuple<int, int>> NivoZaRobaID = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT ROBA.ROBAID, USER_CENOVNIK.NIVO FROM USER_CENOVNIK
                    LEFT JOIN ROBA ON ROBA.CENOVNIK_GRUPAID = USER_CENOVNIK.CENOVNIK_GRUPAID
                    WHERE USER_CENOVNIK.USERID = @U ORDER BY ROBA.ROBAID ASC", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@U", UserID);

                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (dr[0] is DBNull)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        NivoZaRobaID.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), dr[1] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr[1])));
                    }
                }
            }

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ROBAID, NABAVNACENA, PRODAJNACENA FROM ROBA", con))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        MinCene.Add(new WebShop.Cena(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Convert.ToDouble(dr[1])));
                        MaxCene.Add(new WebShop.Cena(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Convert.ToDouble(dr[2])));


                        if (!NivoZaRobaID.Exists(x => x.Item1 == Convert.ToInt32(dr[0])))
                            NivoZaRobaID.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), (int)CenovnikKlasa.Iron));
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (Tuple<int, int> n in NivoZaRobaID)
            {
                double minCena = MinCene.Where(x => x.RobaID == n.Item1).FirstOrDefault().VPCena;
                double maxCena = MaxCene.Where(x => x.RobaID == n.Item1).FirstOrDefault().VPCena;
                double razlika = (maxCena - minCena) * (1 - OD_UKUPNE_RAZLIKE_NAMA_OSTAJE_SIGURNIH);
                double namaOstaje = razlika;

                double K = razlika / (Cenovnik.nLevel - 1) * NivoZaRobaID.Where(x => x.Item1 == n.Item1).FirstOrDefault().Item2;

                if (minCena <= 0 || maxCena <= 0)
                    CeneZaKorisnika.Add(new WebShop.Cena(n.Item1, -9999));
                else
                    CeneZaKorisnika.Add(new WebShop.Cena(n.Item1, maxCena - K));
            }
            return CeneZaKorisnika;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to abstract the details of loading data away from your client/front end.

Create a "Repository" which your client interacts with, so that they request data from here.

The repository could either
Option 1:

- Upon start-up load all data.
- Upon request return the result from memory.
- After xxx minutes/hours refresh data from DB
- During refresh

  - the "old" data remains in memory
  - Repository builds up a new secondary set of the data
  - When secondary data is complete, repository switches to new data set
    and drops the old one.  (You can do this table by table)

Option 2:

- Upon start-up, load all data
- When it receives a request

  - If the request exists in memory, return it.  Else execute against DB
  - Store DB result in memory for future requests
  - If the cached data is > xxx minutes/hours, schedule a refresh as
    background process

But you don't need to reinvent the wheel.  There are libraries out there that help with caching, so look at using them.  Some such as Redis, Hazelcast, etc. also offer distributed caching and all you to set TTL (time to live) for expiry and offer easy to use APIs/client libraries for C#